# UglifyJS not working in Symfony2 production environment

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, symfony, uglifyjs

I believe I configured it properly -- here is my config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    node: "/usr/local/bin/node"
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        uglifyjs2:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs"
        cssrewrite: ~
```

I'm storing uglifyjs locally in the project, just to make it easier for distribution.

I am doing the following to generate all the JS files, using uglifyjs:

```
{% javascripts 
    'vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js'
    'js/test1.js'
    'js/test2.js'
    filter='?uglifyjs2' %}

    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

{% endjavascripts %}
```

If I load the page in dev mode (/app_dev.php), it works fine, and just loads the files individually, but minified by uglifyjs; but if I try to load it in production, it combines all of those js files into one js file (ie. a07da66.js). The problem I'm facing, is that it gets a 404 not found error when trying to load that file (a07da66.js). It tries to access it at `js/a07da66.js` - seems to create them under js/ by default.

Why does it work fine in app_dev.php, when it creates the new files under js/ (js/a07da66_jquery.min_1.js), but not in production?

Comment: Did you run `app/console --env=prod assetic:dump`?

Comment: That did it - can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Would I have to run that after I modify JS files?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to run the dump command to regenerate the assets each time you change the files.

Comment: have you tried `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `app/console --env=prod assetic:dump` to generate the assets for the prod environment.

Rule of thumb:

- While in *dev* mode, keep `app/console assetic:watch --force` running in the background (at least while working on JS/CSS files). It will regenerate *dev* assets whenever a file changes.
- When deploying/building, run `app/console --env=prod assetic:dump` once in order to have the combined assets for *prod* generated.

The idea of the prod mode is that you generate some sort of build or snapshot of your current development. Therefore, you would use `app/console --env=prod assetic:dump` only when creating the build.

Of course, you can switch your *dev* environment to *prod* for a brief test, but then you must perform the build procedure, too (which includes generating the *prod* assets).

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3 + you have to run `bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod` to generate the files for the prod environment.

In case you made a modification on the assets you have to run `bin/console assetic:watch` each time to regenerate the files.